# Not able to get get_term_link in product-attributes.php woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have the below code:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat');
    foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
        $product_cat_name .= $term->name . ', ';
    } 
?>
    
    <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
    <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Category', 'webinweb'); ?></th>
     <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value" ><?php echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $term->taxonomy).'">'.$product_cat_name.'</a>'; ?> </td>
    <tr>
```

The link to each product-category is set by 'get_term_slug'. But this is always the same product-category link and not the product-category link for that product.

What do I need to add to get this working?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here, but `$term` will of course always contain the _last_ of your terms _after_ the foreach loop ...

Comment: Hi CBroe,
On a single product page in WooCommerce we have a tab that displays the product attributes like weight, dimension etc.
I would like to add the categories the product belongs to. This is working fine. I can display the categories the product belongs to. Now I need the permalink /slug to these individual categories. Thus by clicking on the categorie the user will be directed to the category page.

Comment: You are currently not creating a link for each category, you are creating _one_ link, and then you set the comma-separated list of category names as the link text. If you want one link for each category, then the creation of those links of course belongs _into_ your loop over the categories, not after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code worked for me

```
<?php
global $product;
$prodId = $product->get_id();
$terms = get_the_terms( $prodId, 'product_cat');
$product_cat_name = '';
foreach ($terms  as $term  ) {
   $product_cat_name .= '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $term->taxonomy).'">'.$term->name . '</a>';
} 
?>
<table class="woocommerce-product-attributes shop_attributes">
    <?php foreach ( $product_attributes as $product_attribute_key => $product_attribute ) : ?>
        <tr class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item woocommerce-product-attributes-item--<?php echo esc_attr( $product_attribute_key ); ?>">
        <th class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__label"><?php esc_html_e( 'Category', 'webinweb'); ?></th>
        <td class="woocommerce-product-attributes-item__value" ><?php echo $product_cat_name; ?> </td>
     </tr>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @quinox you can check answer and accept as per required